# Is it possible to run jobs on remote executors with APScheduler?

Tags: job-scheduling, apscheduler

Does APScheduler only work on the localhost, or is it possible to use remote executors?
The default *ThreadPoolExecutor* and *ProcessPoolExecutor* seem to only spawn threads or processes on the main server.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but I have tentative plans to add such a thing to APScheduler 3.1 or another future version. None of the existing job queue libraries I looked at were a good fit.